# How to set up IIS on Windows 7 for security?

Tags: windows-7, iis, internet-security

I have a Windows 7 Ultimate PC I use as a server. I have IIS running and would like to expose it to the internet for personal use.

I have no idea where to start doing that without letting the world and his dog onto my private network.

This is as far as I've got (Not set up yet, just planning)

1. Port forward external port 80 to IIS Server port 80.
2. On server block any traffic that isn't to port 80 that originates from an external address (Is that right? Or would I use my router address on the private side?
3. Configure IIS – no idea about this one.

Are there any guides to this? What should I look out for specifically?

Comment: #2: NAT does this for you. In fact, a combination of even the ugliest router ever and the fact that hackers are lazy already reduces your risk of attack about 50%. What I would be concerned about the most is hardening the IIS process (#3).

Comment: Yep, I've done more research since I origanally posted (Isn't it remarkable how all the stuff you couldn't find comes out after you post :) )